# Basic auth header in Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, authentication, alamofire

I have a protected api and I got the username and password for it. When I use Postman I select the "Basic Auth" type and in the body I have the parameters such as the user login info. It works just fine.

[image]

However I'm trying to do the same thing with Alamofire but I can't get the right JSON return. Here is what I did :

```
  // user auth 
  let param = ["mobile":"3", "password":"100200"]
    let urlStr = "http://MyApi.com/api/login"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)

    // api auth 
    let user = "apiUserName"
    let password = "ApiAuthPassword"


    var headers: HTTPHeaders = ["mobile":"001",
                                "password":"1111"]

    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }

    Alamofire.request(url!, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            print(response.result.value)
            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                print(value)
                let usertoken = JSON(value)

                print(usertoken)
            }



    }
```

This returns nil. Can someone help me how to do the Postman method with Alamofire. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let user = "your username"

let password = "your password"

let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!

let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()


   let headers = [
            "Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)", 
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json" ]

//put slash before \ (base64Credentials)

    Alamofire.request("place your url", method: .get, parameters: nil,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers) .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(_):   
               //your success code
            }      
            case .failure(_):
               //your failure code
            }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you would use the create this base64EncodedString yourself. Alamofire has its own implementation of exactly what has been done here. Just pass your username and password and it will create a basic auth HTTP header.`HTTPHeader.authorization(username: username,
                                       password: password)`. Then pass this into your headers.

Comment: please share syntax for swift 5 (latest version of alamofire)