# How do I request an access token using alamofire?

Tags: swift, curl, alamofire

I want to try blizzard API using alamofire.

However, it was difficult to find the example.

The code below is a method to request an access token using curl provided on the Blizzard official website.

```
curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} -d grant_type=client_credentials https://us.battle.net/oauth/token
```

An example response to this is below.

```
{"access_token": "...", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 86399, "scope": "example.scope"}
```

As above,

How do I request an access token using alamofire (in swift)?

*I already know the client_id and client_secret.

Comment: If your concern is how to send `{client_id}: {client_secret}` check how to basic authorization headers using alamofire (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833743/basic-auth-header-in-alamofire)

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#authentication + since you have `cURL`, you can check that you are doing the same with curl output of Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#curl-command-output